# Is the SPAD-T textual analysis software still available?

Tags: software

I am looking for an old program called SPAD-T that is still used for textual analysis (especially in psychology).

Can anybody tell me where I can download or purchase a legal copy?  Failing that, does anyone know how I could contact the original publisher/developer?

Note that I have [cross-posted the question here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8942/linguistics-software-spad-t).

Comment: There is a quiet similar but more recent software called Iramuteq which you can download from the web (also developed by the French).

Answer (score 3):

After a little bit of googling, it seems that the original developer of SPAD-T, [CISIA](http://www.cisia.com/) (dead link), is no longer in business, and the software appears to have become unavailable. I found the company off [this list](http://www.unige.ch/ses/sococ/aqual/links/qualsoft.html), so maybe it will be of some help in finding an alternative.

(I'm mostly answering this because I suspected that it otherwise never would be.)